# Migrating from JavaFX 2.2 to JavaFX8 is causing deployment problems

Tags: java, javafx-8

I tried upgrading from JavaFX 2.2 to JavaFX 8. My applications runs perfectly from within the Netbeans IDE, but it doesn't when I try to deploy it, I get the following error:

```
CacheEntry[file:/Users/dynelight/Dropbox/PruebasEspecificas/pruebas-especificas/dist/PlataformaValidezPredictiva.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon Mar 23 22:12:20 CST 2015,length=186644
CacheEntry[file:/Users/dynelight/Dropbox/PruebasEspecificas/pruebas-especificas/dist/lib/jfxswt.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Feb 10 14:08:58 CST 2015,length=33793
CacheEntry[file:/Users/dynelight/Dropbox/PruebasEspecificas/pruebas-especificas/dist/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Nov 18 12:37:18 CST 2014,length=827901
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3211)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at plataformavalidezpredictiva.PlataformaValidezPredictiva.start(PlataformaValidezPredictiva.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1526012221.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/326549596.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:159)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1526012221.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/326549596.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3211)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at plataformavalidezpredictiva.PlataformaValidezPredictiva.start(PlataformaValidezPredictiva.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:143)
    ... 6 more
```

PlataformaValidezPredictiva.java:22 has the following:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/Login.fxml"));
```

Any ideas?

Directory Structure (Sorry it's a bit messy):

[image]

Comment: Using `fxml/Login.fxml` depends on where the *current file* and the *fxml* is present. Try using a more generalized form i.e. `/fxml/Login.fxml`

Comment: I tried using a more generalized form. I used         ```Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/plataformavalidezpredictiva/fxml/Login.fxml"));``` ... Same issue. Loads within Netbeans but not as webstart or browser app.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the projects directory structure?

Comment: Can you unzip the created jar and check if the fxml is copied in them or not?

Comment: Just done, and the fxml is indeed copied on the jar...

Comment: @DynelightAre you solve your issue?

Comment: To get further assistance,u ou will probably need to create an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue and edit your question to include the mcve code.  Note both the minimal, complete, verifiable and executable nature of an mcve and ensure that the code you post fulfills all of those requirements.

Comment: @erhun Not yet. Was suggested to create a MVCE but I don't know how to in this case.